# SQLite. LoadExtension() не загружает модуль mod_spatialite.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, sqlite

**Привет!**

**Задача:** Необходимо вытянуть геометрию из пространственной БД SQLite на Spatialite в приложении на C# (WPF .NetFramework 4.8). Для этого я выполняю команду `SELECT AsText(geometry)` к записям базы данных.

**В чем проблема**: Для того что бы выполнить AsText() нужно подключить модуль Spatialite к SQLite через LoadExtension(), что у меня и не получается.

Пытался через `connection.LoadExtinsion("mod_spatialite")`
Ошибка: `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: "SQL logic error Не найден указанный модуль."` (хотя модуль есть в папке с приложением, также пробовал указывать путь к нему - проблема не уходит)

Пытался через `command.CommandText = "SELECT load_extension(\'mod_spatialite\')";`
Ошибка: `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: "SQL logic error not authorized"` (хотя `connection.EnableExtensions(true);` прописан, и в sqlite3.exe, о котором в P.S. написано, ошибок не возникает)

```
    private void test()
        {
            var connectionStr = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                DataSource = "polygonSpat.sqlite"
            }.ToString();
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                connection.EnableExtensions(true);
                connection.LoadExtension("mod_spatialite.dll");
                //command.CommandText = "SELECT load_extension(\'mod_spatialite\')";
                //command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command.CommandText = "select AsText(geometry) from kek ";

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Пробовал как с помощью System.Data.SQLite, так и с помощью Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.

**P.S.** Скачал [отсюда](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64-prev/) spatialite-loadable-modules-5.0.0-win-amd64.7z, в котором есть sqlite3.exe, который загружает mod_spatialite с помощью `SELECT load_extension(\'mod_spatialite\')` без проблем и выполняет AsText(). Там же брал spatialite_gui, который работает без проблем.

**P.P.S.** Пытался собрать сам по [этой инструкции](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/mingw64_how_to.html), но MSYS2 не стал обновляться, а без обновлений он работать не захотел. Также надо будет запускать мое приложение на других ПК, а каждый раз проводить сборку библиотек на других ПК не хочется, поэтому такой вариант не подходит, однако, может собирать надо один раз... В свою очередь spatial_gui доказывает, что должно быть все проще.

**P.P.P.S.** Нет метки spatialite, что расстраивает. [UPD: Метка есть)]

Comment: На данном этапе я в отчаянии... Придумал только два пути решения данной проблемы: 1) чтение geometry по байтам (в чем уже имею некоторые успехи); 2) запуск sqlite3.exe как процесс из C# и парсинг ответов на команды. Оба варианта костыльные.

Comment: Я добавил метку. Но она может быть удалена, если ей не будут пользоваться (не будет новых вопросов с ней). PS: начиная с 300 очков репутации вы сами сможете создавать метки

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо! Надеюсь это поможет найти мой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спустя несколько дней решение было найдено (не мной, а гением)!!
В общем более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/extensions).
Если вкратце, то необходимо в переменной среды PATH прописать путь до директории с модулями Spatialite для SQLite.
Так же приведу пример кода, в котором PATH подменяется только для процесса приложения.
В примере mod_spatialite.dll лежит в папке с программой, однако, его можно положить в любое другое место (не проверял с кириллицей в пути).
Использовался NuGet пакет Microsoft.Data.Sqlite на WPF .NetFramework 4.8.

```
    private void test()
        {
            var connection = new SqliteConnection(@"Data Source=polygonSpat.sqlite");
            connection.Open();
            //Получаем путь до директории с модулями SQLite. В данном случае была взята директория, в которой находится приложение
            string modDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            //Получаем переменную среды path и меняем ее
            string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) + ";" + modDirectory;
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

            //Загружаем модуль
            connection.LoadExtension("mod_spatialite");

            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            //Пишем любую команду Spatialite
            command.CommandText =
            @"
                SELECT AsText(geometry) from polygonspat
            ";

            //Работает!
            Tb1.Text = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

**P.S.** Если у вас будет возникать ошибка: "...не является win32 приложением", то необходимо зайти в свойства проекта->сборка, там нужно снять галочку "предпочтительна 32-разрядная версия".